# 9:1 unun material and power loss

Tags: balun, ferrite, end-fed-antenna, transformer

I need to build another 9:1 unun and I start searching for my toroids... (I have build 2-3 something like 4 years ago)...
In parallel I checked on Google about the correct toroid etc so I found 2-3 pages with designs. My focus is on power loss as I run QRP on batteries.

[9:1  voltage unun using a L15 ferrite core](http://vk6ysf.com/unun_9-1_v2.htm)

[9:1 Voltage Unun - FT240-61](https://g8jnj.webs.com/balunsandtuners.htm)

[9:1  voltage unun using a T-200-2 powdered iron toroid core](http://vk6ysf.com/unun_9-1.htm)

What do you think regarding power losses and materials?
Which toroid should I use? (I already have the *-61 and the *-2).

Regarding wires for the turns, some use enameled copper wire, some 3-colour for like a power socket.

The unun is not for portable. So a size 200-240 is okay for some future proofing.

---

If I can get ok losses down to 80m, I'll be very happy, I mainly use 15 to 40m.

---

It's for a “random wire” end fed. Probably around 58ft max. Or maybe 53ft (space restricted)

Comment: Welcome to this site! The [balun] tag [also covers unun](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tags/balun/info), so I added that.

Comment: This is for an end-fed antenna, right? Is it the same antenna for all those bands? How long is it?

Comment: Its for a “random wire” end fed. Probably around 58ft max. Or maybe 53ft (space restricted)

Comment: You might find [this similar question and the answers](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/12389/do-i-need-an-91-unun-for-a-half-wave-end-fed) particularly useful. On some bands, a 9:1 transformation ratio (50 ohms to 450 ohms) might not be optimal, as the feedpoint impedance might be much higher or much lower than 450 ohms.

Comment: I copied your comment with your antenna info into the answer. Note that comments are not searchable, and such details should be in the answer itself.